# clang-diagnostic-error - allocating an object of abstract class type 'Base'

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
protected:
    int num{ 1 };

public:
    Base() {
        cout << "Base class constructor" << endl;
    }
     virtual ~Base() 
    {
        cout << "Base class destructor " << endl;
    }
private:
};

class Derive : public Base {
public:
    Derive() {
        cout << "Derive class constructor" << endl;
    }
    ~Derive() {
        cout << "Derive class destructor " << endl;
    }
public:
    void foo() override{
        cout << "Derive class Foo function" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    unique_ptr<Base> b = make_unique<Base>(new Derive());
    b->foo();   
}
```

I get below error when I build this code.

1. in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::make_unique<Base, Derive *>' requested here unique_ptr b = make_unique(new Derive());
2. unimplemented pure virtual method 'foo' in 'Base' virtual void foo() = 0;

Does anyone know what is the reason of this error?

Note: I tried on https://godbolt.org/ and selected clang 11

Comment: Please, format the code appropriately, Prapeer.

Comment: `make_unique` doesn't take a pointer to the thing you want to stick in the smart pointer.  It takes the actual constructor arguments.  So, it wants to create a `Base`.  But it can't, because `Base` is abstract.  Solution here is _not_ to write a `Base::foo()` but instead to do the right thing:  Just call `unique_ptr`'s constructor given your pointer to `Derived`.

Comment: `make_unique<T>` creates a *new* uniquely-owned object of type `T`. It does not take ownership of an existing thing. (It's "make" as in "make me a pizza", not as in "make me a millionaire".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main()` function, do this instead:
`unique_ptr<Base> b(new Derive());`

This is because `std::make_unique()` takes the actual constructor arguments. You can't do that with polymorphism, but there's nothing wrong with directly instanstiating a `std::unique_ptr` directly with a heap allocated resource.

Do prefer `std::make_unique()` where it makes sense, though. This just isn't one of those cases.